# Parameter is not valid error when creating new bitmap

Tags: asp.net, image, bitmap

I am displaying images on my page and then attempting to find the current height of the images in order to vertically position them. I am doing this by creating a new bitmap and then getting the height of the bitmap, as follows:

```
Dim sampleImg As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(Server.MapPath(String.Format("/Uploads/Products/Images/w100h100/{0}", e.Item.DataItem("Filename"))))
Dim imgHeight As Integer = sampleImg.Height
```

When I run this on my local machine, all works fine. However, I have recently uploaded the site so far to my development server and when I run the same code from there, I get this error message:

> Parameter is not valid

I have been searching forums to try to find a solution but I have ended up a bit unsure where else to look because the file definitely exists on the development server and the code works fine on my local machine. The server I am using is a VPS and I am quite a beginner with working with servers so I don't know if there is anything I haven't set up on there which is stopping it from working?

Whilst trying to find a solution, I have also tried the following code but I get a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` error message:

```
Dim sampleImg As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(String.Format("/Uploads/Products/Images/w100h100/{0}", e.Item.DataItem("Filename"))))
```

I am wondering if anyone can help me find a solution to this, or alternatively is there a different method to acheiving the same end?

All help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: When debugging, does the full path match the actual full path of the image? E.g have you tried copy/pasting this into windows explorer, and does it return the image?

Comment: Thanks for your help - yes I have tried this so I know that the image does definitely exist in that location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be a file permissions issue, you need to ensure that the IUSR account for your site has read access to the image file. To do this -

R-click the file, Properties, Select the "Security" tab - you will have a list of users who have access to the file. A quick check is to add "Everyone" with read priviliges. To keep it locked to your ASP.Net instance only you should start IIS Manager, r-click your app pool and the Identity is the user your app runs under.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running through IIS it may be that the file type isn't set up in the available MIME types for the site.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742440.aspx

With IIS7 there is a module for each Site called "MIME Types". Check whether the File Extension is in the list, and if not, add it with the appropriate MIME Type (list of mime types in link above)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I've just checked but all the image file types that are relevant are already added in the list so it doesn't seem to be that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `~` root operator to resolve the path issue.

```
Dim sampleImg As System.Drawing.Image = 
          System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(
          String.Format("~/Uploads/Products/Images/w100h100/{0}", 
          e.Item.DataItem("Filename"))))
```

OR the specified file is not a valid image file.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - unfortunately this hasn't made any difference and I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: @Leah : Are you disposing all image objects after that part of code is executed? Write a small code and test/run what happen at development server.

Comment: I wasn't originally disposing of the Image object but I have now added a bit of code to dispose of the object after using it. This unfortunately still hasn't made any difference on the development server, and I am still getting the System.IO.FileNotFoundException error message.

Comment: @Leah - Please verify the path of folder "Uploads" on development server. Is this folder under the root of web-app context?

Comment: Yes that's correct. It's located at the root of the web application. I know the file exists because if I paste the path starting from "/Uploads..." into the address bar after the domain to view the actual image, the image loads as expected.

Comment: @Leah :) So why this code throws FileNotFoundException? I guess something is missing.

Comment: I really don't know! It seems very strange that the file can't be found when creating a new bitmap - the same image path displays as an image on the page no problems - it's only when I'm trying to create a bitmap using that filepath that the problem occurs.

Comment: Is it a permissions issue? Have you checked that the file you are trying to load has read permissions assigned to the ASP.Net worker process?

Comment: @Wolfwyrd Thanks for your help. It may be a permissions issue - the only place I'm getting this problem seems to be on my VPS. I've tried uploading the files to a live server to test if it happens there and there is no error when viewing the page on that server. How do I check if the file has read permissions assigned to the ASP.NET worker process on my VPS? Apologies if this is a simple question!!

Comment: If you r-click the file, Properties, Select the "Security" tab you will have a list of users who have access to the file. A quick check is to add "Everyone" with read priviliges. To keep it locked to your ASP.Net instance only you should start IIS Manager, r-click your app pool and the Identity is the user your app runs under.

Comment: @Wolfwyrd Excellent! Thanks for your help - I have tested it by adding "Everyone" like you suggested and the error has now disappeared. I'm not sure if I've set the website up properly but when I set it up, I set it to be authenticated by the Administrator user rather than pass-through authentication. The Administrator user already has read permission on the files that are causing the problem, so which user should I set to have read permissions instead?

Comment: @Wolfwyrd I have added "IIS_IUSRS" to the list of users that have permission to read the files and removed "Everyone". It is still working - have I done that correctly? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @Leah yep, looks like you've got it :) Well done! I'll add this as an answer so you can flag it for future reference

Comment: @Wolfwyrd That's great thanks a lot! I'll mark your answer as correct when you've posted it :)